# Is it bad programming practice to relate two objects with both inheritance and aggregation?

Tags: inheritance, uml, aggregation

I have a class that represents an electrical device (let's call it class 1). I also have a class that represents multiple devices, essentially an array of devices joined together (class 2).

It obviously makes sense to have an aggregation relationship, whereby an instance of class 1 is contained within class 2. However in my usage it is common to also consider class 2 as a larger instance of class 1 (in a similar way as a bank of batteries could also be thought of as a single battery).

This means that I want to reuse all of the methods and attributes from class 1 in class 2, while also adding a few additional ones. In my mind this means that an inheritance relationship also makes sense: but where some of the attributes are derived from the embedded parent object rather than being defined by the user.

Is this something that is commonly done? I am quite new to programming but have not seen a UML diagram with two separate lines between a parent and child class. Is my approach bad programming practice and is there a better representation of such relationships?

Comment: I'd favor aggregation over inheritance when possible. In this case you could just drop your class2 and use class1 with a list of itself inside. Just like a tree. I've never had the need for inheritance at the same time that aggregation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right, the pattern you describe sounds like a pattern called "composite" - which is not uncommon nor is it bad practice [have a look here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

In general you are right, try to keep the coupling between classes as low as possible (inheritance is really strong in that regard). But if it makes sense and eases the understanding of your code implement it that way. Be pragmatic about patterns and techniques. If inheritance makes sense and truly models the relationship between your classes then use it.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I’d add is that in principle there’s nothing wrong with two types having more than one relationship with each other, it all depends on your specifics. In your case it would simply mean that Class 2 is a kind of Class 1, and that Class 2 aggregates Class 1. So in other words, it’s a kind of Class 1 that can aggregate further Class 1s. So that could be represented using both an aggregation and a generalisation between the two classes. However, I’d agree with the other respondents that in your case I’m not sure this is a great design, because Class 2 really isn’t actually a kind of Class 1, your just using inheritance to reuse code and you may do better to look at breaking the classes down further into their composite parts and promote reuse that way. You could consider an interface to define the common characteristics of Class 1 that you want Class 2 to implement so that they can be treated polymorphically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is not any Inheritance between Class1 and Class2. The reason that (I want to use class1 methods in class2) is not enough to use Inheritance. You can you Class1 methods only by an instance of Class1 into Class2. It is only Aggregation.

For example if we want to use an array of String in one class, we do not inherit String. For another example, (from real world), a book is not a kind of paper or An apartment is not a kind of Room. A group of persons is not kind of a person.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [composite pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite) here.